# How to search an array of data items for a specifically matching item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, find

I need to do a search in the below provided array so that when I search for a `pin` value of `'002'` I should get the `area` value of `'F02'`.

```
[{
  pin: "001",
  area: "F01",
}, {
  pin: "002",
  area: "F02",
}, {
  pin: "003",
  area: "F07",
}, {
  pin: "004",
  area: "F08",
}]
```

Comment: `arrayName.find({pin} => pin==='002')` will give the object. extract area from that

Comment: Do you have a JSON document (ie, a string), or a JavaScript object?

Comment: There is nothing like a JSON array or JSON object. JS data-structures can be provided and transferred/interchanged as [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) strings (see [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). Such strings can be converted back into objects by a parse process like `JSON.parse`. Thus `JSON` stands for both, a JavaScript namespace with methods and a syntax for serializing data-structures.

Comment: @Raj ... in case there are no questions left and especially if an answer does solve the problem, [the OP might consider flagging the most helpful answer as the *accepted* one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/251298#251298).

Answer (score 1):

Use `array.filter`:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
const arr = [{
  pin: "001",
  area: "F01",
}, {
  pin: "002",
  area: "F02",
}, {
  pin: "003",
  area: "F07",
}, {
  pin: "004",
  area: "F08",
}];

// the resulting array of a successful filter process.
console.log(
  'the resulting array of a successful filter process ...',
  arr.filter(i => i.pin === '002')
);
// accessing the `area` property of the first matching item.
console.log(
  'accessing the `area` property of the first matching item ...',
  arr.filter(i => i.pin === '002')[0].area
);
console.log('\n');

// the resulting array of a non matching filter process.
console.log(
  'the resulting array of a non matching filter process ...',
  arr.filter(i => i.pin === '005')
);
// safely accessing the not assured first items's `area` property of an unknow filter result.
console.log(
  "safely accessing the not assured first items's `area` property of an unknow filter result ...",
  arr.filter(i => i.pin === '005')[0]?.area
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Use `array.find`:

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that
> satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the
> testing function, undefined is returned.

```js
const arr = [{
  pin: "001",
  area: "F01",
}, {
  pin: "002",
  area: "F02",
}, {
  pin: "003",
  area: "F07",
}, {
  pin: "004",
  area: "F08",
}];

// object which satisfies the condition does exist.
console.log(
  'object which satisfies the condition does exist ...',
  arr.find(i => i.pin === '002')
);
// accessing the `area` property of the well known return value.
console.log(
  'accessing the `area` property of the well known return value ...',
  arr.find(i => i.pin === '002').area
);
console.log('\n');

// object which satisfies the condition does not exist.
console.log(
  'object which satisfies the condition does not exist ...',
  arr.find(i => i.pin === '005')
);
// safely accessing the possible `area` property of a varying/unsafe return value.
console.log(
  'safely accessing the possible `area` property of a varying/unsafe return value ...',
  arr.find(i => i.pin === '005')?.area
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

If you want to find a specific item, always consider use the `array.find` since its orginal goal is to find a sepecific item in the `array`, but the goal of `array.filter` is to use run a test to all item in `array` and return the pass item.

Important note by [Peter Seliger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627243/peter-seliger):

> find stops iterating the processed array as soon as the condition matches, whereas filter always does a full loop

Array.find on your situation will have much better performance speed and save your calculation time since `array.find` will immediately return the item you find, but `array.filter` will iterate all the item in the `array` whatever

Comment: An additional explanation about the differences of `filter` vs `find` and why the OP for the provided use case should exclusively use the latter is much needed.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, thanks for pointing that. I have edited my answer with quote and a little explanation

Comment: Equally important, if not most important, **`find` stops iterating the processed array as soon as the condition matches, whereas `filter` always does a full loop** in order to collect all matching elements.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, totally agree, wow, I miss a lot, sorry and thanks! I have edited and all included in my answer!

Answer (score -2):

```
You could just loop through the array and find the matches:
`var results = [];
 var searchField = "pin";
 var searchVal = "area";
 for (var i=0 ; i < obj.list.length ; i++)
 {
    if (obj.list[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
        results.push(obj.list[i]);
 }
}`
```